# Unity 2D, C# - Creating an AI that both follows the player and flutters around him

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, sprite

First of all, I am EXTREMELY new to coding in general, but I've picked it up as a hobby, so please forgive my general lack of understanding.

I am putting together a sidescrolling platformer, in which a small character follows you around and gives you advice, lights the way, fills in lore, etc. Think Navi from Legend of Zelda. I already have a functioning script for following the player around, which I will post below.

However, I cannot get it to then lazily float around the character rather than just sitting still.

```
public class WillOWispFollowPlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
public Transform target;

public float smoothSpeed = 0.05f;
public Vector3 offset;


private void FixedUpdate()
  {

    Vector3 desiredPosition = target.position + offset;
    Vector3 smoothedPosition = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, desiredPosition, smoothSpeed);
    transform.position = smoothedPosition;

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't dabbled to far into game development, but how I would go about it is to implement some random location with a bias towards the player or a target position near the player.

So, say that at semi even intervals, you generate a new random position or direction for your companion to move towards to, the distance should be relatively close to the companions current location. To prevent your companion randomly flying off, *into the sunset*, you should also make sure that this random location or direction is biased towards the players location, for example, the further away it is from the player, the more biased it will be to move towards the player.

Comment: This could work, but it seems somewhat complex for the purpose. I just need the AI not to sit perfectly still when the character is idle. A thought I had would be applying a rigid body to the AI, and then gently adding force in random directions. I'll mess around with some things and see what I come up with.

Answer (score 0):

After hammering away at this for a while, and looking at some other people's code, this is what I've come up with. It adds two functions to the original code. One is a random direction function with adjustable acceleration and deceleration which is applied in FixedUpdate. The other is a short burst of velocity in a separate random direction. The effect is more fluttery than I originally intended, and less of a floaty wander effect, but it works. If anyone has any ideas to make this a less jittery and more smooth, floaty effect, Im open to suggestions.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody2D))]
public class WillOWispFollowPlayer : MonoBehaviour
{

public Transform target;

public float smoothSpeed = 0.05f;
public float smoothSpeedSlow = 0.02f;
public Vector3 offset;
public float hoverSpeed = 10000f;
public Rigidbody2D rb;
public static System.Timers.Timer hoverTimer;

public float acceleration;
public float deceleration;

private Rigidbody2D physics;
private Vector2 direction;

private void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    InvokeRepeating("HoverDirection", 0, 1); //calling the DoverDirection every second

    physics = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    physics.gravityScale = 0;
    physics.drag = deceleration;
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    Vector3 desiredPosition = target.position + offset;
    Vector3 smoothedPosition = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, desiredPosition, smoothSpeed);
    Vector3 smoothedPositionSlow = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, desiredPosition, smoothSpeedSlow);

    //setting up a "wander zone" where the Will'o'the'Wisp is less restricted within a defined distance of the player
    if (Vector3.Distance((target.position + offset), this.transform.position) >= .5)
    {
        transform.position = smoothedPosition;
    }
    else
    {
        transform.position = smoothedPositionSlow;
    }

    //Random direction generator This results in a "flutter" effect
    direction = UnityEngine.Random.insideUnitCircle;

    Vector2 directionalForce = direction * acceleration;
    physics.AddForce(directionalForce * Time.deltaTime, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
}

//A regular and prominant directional change, resulting in short darting motions around the target position
void HoverDirection() 
{
    rb.velocity = Random.onUnitSphere * hoverSpeed;
}
}
```